# What happens when the tab button is hit in a WPF rich text box?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, tabstop

Ok.

So I get that when the tab key is hit once (with AllowTab = true), that the paragraph's textIndent property is set to 20.

What I don't understand is this. When I hit the tab key twice, the paragraph is indented twice. So I would assume that it's textIndent would be set to 40....but it is still set to 20.

There are no spaces inserted before the text, so I do not understand how the text indents more, when the textIndent is the same for both 1 tab and 2 tabs.

Anyone know how this works?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph's left `Margin` is increased by 20 every consecutive tab.

Comment: thanks! that is totally it. Why they do it this way, and not just increment one or the other is beyond me